# ImageCropper: fails with unhelpful error message on very large pictures

Tags: java, primefaces, png, image-cropper

Using Primefaces's `ImageCropper` component, cropping a png image of 15,000 x 12,000 pixels fails, the only error trace I get is `error reading png data`. There is no error trace logged on my local IDE.

- local IDE: NetBeans
- JDK: 17
- server: Payara

Answer (score 1):

The error was investigated [in a Github issue posted on the Primefaces repo](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/10373).

It seems that the issue lays in the JDK, not in Primefaces. The error disappears when:

- the image is converted to jpg
- or a smaller png image is used

There is no reason for Primefaces to work on solving this issue and I document it here for future users.